how to create a rest endpoint , which will accept the soap xml file as input and call soap endpoint
how to create a rest endpoint , which will accept the soap xml file as input and call spring boot soap endpoint with same xml and get the response back from soap endpoint
sample snippet of code, kindly let me know if you need any further details

You can use this code lines
@PostMapping("/invokeSoapEndpoint")
public String invokeSoapEndpoint(@RequestBody String soapRequest) {
    // Assuming soapRequest is the SOAP XML content
    
    // Create a RestTemplate to call the SOAP endpoint
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    
    // Set the SOAP endpoint URL
    String soapEndpointUrl = "http://example.com/soap-endpoint";
    
    // Make the SOAP request and get the response
    String soapResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(soapEndpointUrl, soapRequest, String.class);
    
    // Return the SOAP response
    return soapResponse;
}

RestTemplate is coming from : import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
Also if you need an example you can view here.
